# Optimization for Date Correlation doesn’t change plan

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2005

I have a reporting requirement from the following tables. I created a new database with these tables and imported data from the live database for reporting purpose.

The report parameter is a date range. I read the following and found that `DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION` can be used to make the query work faster by utilizing seek instead of scan. I made the required settings – still the query is using same old plan and same execution time. What additional changes need to be made to make the query utilize the date correlation?

Note: I am using SQL Server 2005

**REFERENCES**

1. [Optimizing Queries That Access Correlated datetime Columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177416(v=sql.105).aspx)
2. [The Query Optimizer: Date Correlation Optimisation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-query-optimizer-date-correlation-optimisation/)

**SQL**

```
--Database change made for date correlation
ALTER DATABASE BISourcingTest
   SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION ON;
GO

--Settings made
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO

--Test Setting
IF (  (sessionproperty('ANSI_NULLS') = 1) AND
      (sessionproperty('ANSI_PADDING') = 1) AND 
      (sessionproperty('ANSI_WARNINGS') = 1) AND 
      (sessionproperty('ARITHABORT') = 1) AND 
      (sessionproperty('CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL') = 1) AND 
      (sessionproperty('QUOTED_IDENTIFIER') = 1) AND 
      (sessionproperty('NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT') = 0)  
    )
   PRINT 'Everything is set'
ELSE
   PRINT 'Different Setting'

--Query
SELECT C.ContainerID, C.CreatedOnDate,OLIC.OrderID
FROM ContainersTest C
INNER JOIN OrderLineItemContainers OLIC
    ON OLIC.ContainerID = C.ContainerID
WHERE C.CreatedOnDate > '1/1/2015'
AND C.CreatedOnDate < '2/01/2015'
```

**TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContainersTest](
    [ContainerID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [XPKContainersTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CreatedOnDate] ASC,
    [ContainerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderLineItemContainers](
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LineItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContainerID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_POLineItemContainers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC,
    [LineItemID] ASC,
    [ContainerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_OrderLineItemContainers] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ContainerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderLineItemContainers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_POLineItemContainers_Containers] FOREIGN KEY([ContainerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Containers] ([ContainerID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderLineItemContainers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_POLineItemContainers_Containers]
```

**Plan**
[image]

--

Comment: Have you tried dropping the current query plan and rerunning so that it creates a new one?

Comment: @JohnSpecko I tried after following command also - but no change. `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;`

Comment: hmmm. That is strange, I'll have to do some additional digging.

Comment: Did you import enough data from the live database into your test database? The query optimizer will use a scan if there is not much data to cover.

Comment: I created your tables on a test database (SS2012). The tables are empty of course; I'm getting two index seeks + nested loop for inner join. Might be that the optimizer on your SQL Server instance thinks it's faster to do a seek + scan, and a hash match for the inner join. Also, do yourself a favor, use `YYYYMMDD` as date format.

Comment: After you created tables and imported data, table indexes may get fragmented and table statistics may get outdated or happen to not be representative after auto-updating. Try doing `alter index all on [tableName] rebuild` plus `update statistics [tableName] with fullscan` for both tables participating in the query. And then re-test your query.

Comment: @i-one I tired index rebuild and statistics update. After that used `FREEPROCCACHE`. Still same plan and same time (only slight change in % - 53 to 54 in Hash match)

Comment: I agree with @TT.: this is probably an optimizer choice based on the amount of data. If you force an `INNER LOOP JOIN`, you may see a `SEEK` on both tables - but you're likely to face a performance hit. For others on SQL Server 2008 or later, you could also try using `WITH(FORCESEEK)`.

Comment: @StevenHibble Then what is the use of  `DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION` ?

Comment: @Lijo Perhaps you can look into [the internal view that is created](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/data-correlation-optimization-internals)? Maybe SQL Server is having a hard time finding the correlation.

Comment: Is there a missing unique constraint on dbo.ContainersTest? FK from dbo.OrderLineItemContainers cannnot be created (after changing REFERENCES clause from dbo.Containers to dbo.ContainersTest)

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177416(v=sql.105).aspx

> If any one of the datetime columns for which correlation statistics are maintained is not the first or only key of a clustered index, consider creating a clustered index on it. Doing this generally leads to better performance on the types of queries covered by correlation statistics. If a clustered index already exists on the primary key columns, you can modify a table so that the clustered index and primary key use different column sets.

Since your OrderLineItemContainers table has no suitable index by which to filter on the Date, it really can't do anything. Try adding a nonclustered index on the OrderLineItemContainers.CreatedOnDate to see if it will then switch the plan.

It would be better to have it be clustered, but there are other considerations... note you could make the primary key nonclustered, and use the clustered for this new date index if this is the dominant query and this makes it worth it.

So this is optimal:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderLineItemContainers](
      [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [LineItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [ContainerID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
      [CreatedOnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
   CONSTRAINT [PK_POLineItemContainers] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED -- NONCLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY!!
        (
            [OrderID] ASC,
            [LineItemID] ASC,
            [ContainerID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
         CONSTRAINT [IX_OrderLineItemContainers] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
        (
            [ContainerID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ON OrderLineItemContainers(CreatedOnDate)
```

OR you could just try a new NONCLUSTERED index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ON OrderLineItemContainers(CreatedOnDate)
```

Comment: Note this as well "You should not enable DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION in update-intensive database environments".  If that's the case, you might want to pursue other optimization strategies...like pulling candidate rows from the ContainersTest table into a temp table first and then doing the second join.

Comment: Thanks for response. But even after adding nonclustered index, it didn'change execution plan and time